# Visa refused under V 4 (A-(C) how to overcome this for new application

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, budget, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a student in London and my mother applied for a visitor visa to come and visit me. But it was unfortunately refused.

Among the reasons for the refusal which you will read in the refusal letter that i ill attach is the fact that the proof of study i provided her was not legible. Also, for some reason, the ECO did not have a record of my new tier 4 visa, instead he had only my previous 6 months visa. the above problems can be easily fixed as i can provide her with a new legible proof of study certificate, my brp, my home office letter, my police registration, proof of address, my CAS letter,social security number, my sponsorship letter (as i am sponsored by my government to study in the UK) my offer letter, y visa montinoring record, a letter from my employer ( i work part-time job) my supervisor will also provide me with a proof of supervision, my birth certificate...etc. Anything i can get my hands on.

But the for financial reasons, i should explain that my mother has at the moment one income which is her pension.However, she used to be a freelance dressmaker. She is a certified dressmaker and used to rent a store in which she worked for a year and a half. It was a profitable business, but she had to stop due to some health issues as she was getting old. Unfortunately she did not mention this business in her first application, and on that basis, the ECO was not satisfied that she would spend 1400 pounds which is 7 times her pension on an 8 days vacation. Please note that my mother's certification and store lease papers are with her. and she can use them for another application.
Please read the refusal letter and advise me on what changes should i make for the next application? should i include my bank statement? I miss my mother so much and i wish she would come visit me.

I have copy pasted the text of the Refusal Letter

> The Decision
>
> You have stated that you intend to travel to the UK to
>   visit your daughter resident in the UK as a student for a period of 8
>   days. Whilst you have provided letter of support from your UK sponsor,
>   I note that the document provided by you is not legible to
>   substantiate her valid leave to remain in the UK until now. From the
>   information I have, your daughter was only granted 6 months short
>   student visa valid until May 2018.
>
> You have indicated on your
>   application form that you are Pensioner with a monthly income of 53342
>   DZD (£352) and I accept on the balance of probabilities that you
>   receive this income. However, you have indicated that you spend 25000
>   DZD (£165.22) per month on living costs and supporting your family,
>   leaving a disposable income of 28342 DZD (£187.30).
>
> You have indicated
>   that your trip to the UK will cost you personally £1400 which
>   represents over 7 times of your disposable income. I am not satisfied
>   that this expenditure is credible when compared to your social and
>   economic circumstances. I am also conscious that this appears to be a
>   significant portion of your life savings and I am not satisfied that
>   this expenditure is credible for a short holiday.
>
> Given above, and on
>   the evidence before me, and the balance of probabilities, I am not
>   satisfied that you have accurately presented your circumstances or
>   intentions in wishing to enter the UK. I am not satisfied that you
>   intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit, that you will not
>   live in the UK through frequent or successive visits, that you are
>   genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor
>   routes. This means that your application for a visit visa has been
>   refused under paragraph V4.2 (a-(c). Rate of exchange £1 = [DZD151.32]
>   (reference www.oanda.com on [14/12/18]
>
> Future Applications
>
> Any future
>   UK visa applications you make will be considered on their individual
>   merits, however you are likely to be refused unless the circumstances
>   of your application change.

Comment: The immigration officer thinks your mother can't afford to spend so much money on such a short trip. Proving that she is a certified dressmaker and that she used to own a business doesn't affect that, because proving things about her past doesn't give her any more money today.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to repeat what was said about financial aspects of applications generally. They are covered extremely well in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e), which is the one linked to in comments.

You say in comments that "My mother used to keep her savings with her a home. When she decided to come visit she had to open a bank account and put the money in there for proof." If you provided no evidence of where that money came from then that is probably one of the reasons for rejection. It looks like a pattern called 'funds parking' Read the above link for more information.

If your mother can provide evidence to show that this money has in fact belonged to her for a long time, that *may* be enough to secure a positive result. It's still a big fraction of her savings, but that's only my opinion. The visa officer's may be different.

If the officer believed that £2800 is not sufficient savings, then adding information about your mother's past business will not help her. They are interested only in her current financial circumstances. No matter how profitable her business was in the past, if it has not generated substantial money that she currently holds in savings (or assets) then it does not make sense for her to spend a large fraction of her annual income on a vacation.

If you were to sponsor your mother, you would have to demonstrate the same thing she does - that you can afford to spend that much money, and that spending it is reasonable. If you were spending savings to do that you would also have to show where those savings came from, or that they had been in your possession for a long time.

Comment: Her current financial circumstances indicate that she is retired. But a great amount of her saving comes from that business, and not only her pension. How can we prove that although she no longer practices that business, indeed more than half of her savings come from it?

Comment: If she has sufficient savings to cover the cost of the trip without hurting herself financially then she just has to present evidence of those savings. It doesn't matter where they come from (as long as they are clearly hers and she has had them a long time). But those savings have to be more than just the cost of the trip. It isn't credible that someone spends all their savings on an 8 day trip.

Comment: My mother's savings are 2800£. She mentioned that she's spending 1400£ on this trip. It is however worth mentioning, that my mother used to keep her savings with her a home. When she decided to come visit she had to open a bank account and put the money in there for proof. So she did not have the money in the account for a long time only for a month or so. But from what i understood, is that they are asking for proof of where the money comes from if not her pension. Also, how long do you think the money should be in the account before we apply again? Thank you.

Comment: `My mother's savings are 2800£` That is an insignificant amount. Unfortunately many or most ECO's fail to acknowledge that people in developing countries have no problem spending a LARGE part of their income/savings on a trip abroad which will not make sense to a westerner. That is the problem. On my second international trip to South Africa as an unemployed new graduate, I essentially spent all my savings and borrowed extra to cover my airfare. That is not strange in developing countries.

Comment: Do you think we have better chances if we state that i will be her sponser? if so, how much should i have in my account? Accomodation is not a problem.

Comment: You absolutely must read the answer I linked to. If you don't understand what is written there all you will do is make applications that are going to be rejected.